How to Integrate Angular Build in Next.js with Functional Angular like Routing?
I am working on a project where I need to integrate an Angular application into a Next.js application. My goal is to have the Angular build (latest version) placed in the public folder of the Next.js project and make sure that Angular routes work properly.

So my Nextjs public folder structure as
**angular-modal **
1.browser
index.html
style-3292.css
main-3223d.js
main-3311s.js
polyfills.js
2.server
some js file


So what I did
I invoke a function in a component
async function fetchContent(){
    const response = await fetch('/angular-modal/browser/index.html');
    const text = await response.text();
    setAngularContent(text);

    // Dynamically load Angular scripts
    const scripts = [
        '/angular-modal/browser/polyfills-6EAL64PA.js',
        '/angular-modal/browser/main-AJ5NADMY.js',
        '/angular-modal/browser/main-SLIBOPMU.js',
    ];

   await scripts.forEach(src => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
  }

I have tried two approaches: loading a script file and not loading the script file.
Without loading the script file, Angular routing does not work.
When loading the script file, there are numerous errors in the console.
So basically angular project was working fine on local and its routing also,
So what step should I take so that angular build should work fine.
While the static UI of the Angular application works fine, the Angular routing does not. When I navigate to different routes within the Angular application, the routing does not function as expected.

Questions:
1.How can I properly configure Next.js to allow Angular routing to work seamlessly?
2.Is there a specific way to set up the server or routing in Next.js to support Angular’s routing mechanism?
3.Are there any additional configurations or scripts needed to make Angular routes work when integrated with Next.js?
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

